# What is the expected value of this problem?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Four letters are typed at random so that each of the $26$ Latin alphabet letters is equally likely, and the letters are typed independently of one another. What is the expected number of times the word $OF$ appears in this $4$ letter random text?

Comment: Please edit to add your work on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the times the word OF appears in this 4 letter random text. It is easy to see that $X$ can be $0$, $1$ or $2$.

$$E(X)=0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)=$$

$$=0+1\cdot \frac{(26^2-1)+26^2+(26^2-1)}{26^4}+2\cdot\frac1{26^4}=\frac{3\cdot 26^2}{26^4}=\frac3{676}$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't get is how you calculated P(X = 1). Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: There are three cases: OFxy, xOFy and xyOF (where x and y are some letters). $P(OFxy)=P(xyOF)=\frac{26^2-1}{26^4}$ -- because OFOF is not allowed -- and $P(xOFy)=\frac{26^2}{26^4}$

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I attempted to do this, by considering X as the sum of 4 Bernoulli Random variables (So attaining the word OF in the first index, the 2nd index, the 3rd index and the 4th index) and then using the linearity of expectation to solve the problem. Would that also work

Comment: Yes that method also works. But basically the two methods are the same: the solution I wrote sums (OFxy where xy is not OF), (xOFy) and (xyOF where xy is not OF) and (OFOF twice). The solution you wrote sums (OFxy), (xOFy) and (xyOF).

Comment: Is there any chance you could please show me the working out for it? I don't know why but I get a slightly different answer to the one above using that method.

Comment: Let $X_1$ be $1$ if the word is like OFxy else $0$, $X_2$ is $1$ if the word is like $xOFy$ else $0$ and $X_3$ be $1$ if the word is like $xyOF$ else $0$. Then $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$ and $E(X_1)=E(X_2)=E(X_3)=\frac{26^2}{26^4}$ so $E(X)=3\cdot \frac{26^2}{26^4}=\frac3{26^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$E(X) = 0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)$$

$$P(X=1)= {2\over 26^2}-{1\over 26^4} $$

$$P(X=2)= {1\over 26^4}$$